# Configure JSON generated by CloudEndpoints

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Google CloudEndpoints to provide REST-Endpoints on Google Appengine.

I want to hide some members available on the POJO on the server. These should not be present in the JSON that gets sent out by the endpoint. A workaround would be to set the member to null before sending it, but there surely must be a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
@ApiSerializationProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
String memberToHide;
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#attributes_2